# PP test in R con trend y drift

Tags: r, estadística, timeseries

Tengo una serie de tiempo univariada: `data` y quiero llevar a cabo el test Philips-Perron test para evaluar estionariedad, pero tengo que hacerlo con constante (drift), constante y tendencia (drift and trend) y sin constante ni tendencia.

He intentado varias opciones:

función `pp.test` del paquete `tseries`:  Esta función no da la opción de incluir una constante o una tendencia (drift or a trend) sin embargo, utilicé este código:  `pp.test(data)`

función `ur.pp` del paquete `urca`: Intenté con el siguiente código: `ur.pp(data, type=c("constant"))` para el requerimiento de solo constante (drift) y `ur.pp(data, type=c("constant", "trend"))` para el requerimiento de constante y tendencia (the drift and trend): El problema es que ambos códigos me dan el mismo resultado para el estadístico del test. También, esta función no me da la opción de especificar un modelo sin constante ni tendencia (not constant and not trend).

Qué creen que puedo hacer?

Comment: Pareciera que el paquete aTSA contempla las opciones que mencionas: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/aTSA/html/pp.test.html

Comment: Pude solucionar mi problema con ese paquete. Muchas gracias!